# Cookies inside script-tag include on cross domains

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain

So I have this page on one domain that has a script-tag pointing on another domain and everytime I refresh the page, a new session_id is generated. This only happens on IE, all other browsers seems to work.

Here is an exemple with code (JS and PHP)

http://domain1.com/index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://domain2.com/index.php"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And on http://domain2.com/index.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("content-type: application/x-javascript");
    echo "alert('".session_id()."');";
?>
```

Open Chrome or Firefox in domain1.com/index.php and you should see an alert box with a session id. Everytime you refresh you always have the same session id.
In IE (I tried with 7, 8 and 9), the session id is always different.
The cookies doesn't seem to be saved properly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Anyone thinks it can be done?

Comment: I found that the default value of the privacy policy in Internet Explorer is Medium and it says : blocks third-party cookies that do not have a compact privacy policy
If I set it to allow all, it works. But is there a way to by-pass this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For documentation purposes, here's the solution I found:

I created a p3p file with the IBM P3P Policy editor (the p3p and CP file)
Uploaded the files in the folder /w3c
And added the following header in the file on the domain2.com P3P: CP="content from the CP generated file"

Comment: You made my day, Frank.  In my PHP server file added `header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"');` and worked like a charm.  IE is always so... (cough, cough) Kind of funny...